# How to push newsstand notification by using EasyAPNS

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, newsstand-kit

I built a push notification app with the help of EasyAPNS. Currently I have another app which is a newsstand application. My question is where can I add payload for newsstand notification?

I added something in class_APNS.php like this before I post message:

```
$usermessage['aps']['content-available'] = 1;
```

But my application can never receive the push notification. (I've already registered for the newsstand push notification already.)

Anybody can help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

My method is correct. Let me explain it in more details. I modified queueMessage function inside the class_APNS.php right before the posting. Here is the code:(I added a flag newsstand to indicate it's a newsstand push or a normal push

```
            if ( $this->newsstand )
            {
                $usermessage['aps']['content-available'] = 1;   
            }
            else {
                if(isset($this->usermessage['aps']['content-available']))
                    unset($this->usermessage['aps']['content-available']);
            }

            $fk_device = $this->db->prepare($deviceid);
            $message = $this->_jsonEncode($usermessage);
            $message = $this->db->prepare($message);
            $delivery = (!empty($when)) ? "'{$when}'":'NOW()';
```

Comment: If you do it this way you will be sending content-available with every push message you send. And your app doesn't report if the user enabled newsstand push messages.

Comment: No. I only send out content-available when the newsstand is enabled. And this is what I want.
The newsstand flag can be set per message. That means even the newsstand application can receive normal push message.

Comment: If this is the only change you made to EasyAPNS, where does the client register for newsstand push messages with your callback?